# Pandas DataRange does not include the rest of excel data

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to get an excel data with all historical data from bitcoin. although, that csv is to large, so I need to get the sheet only in the defined datas.

```html
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

DT_FILE_PATH = 'bitstamp.csv'

DATA_INICIO = '2000-10-10'
DATA_FIM = '2010-10-10'

def getDataSetFile(file_path):
    dt_bitstamp = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    print(dt_bitstamp.head())

    dt_bitstamp = pd.DataFrame(dt_bitstamp, index=pd.date_range(DATA_INICIO, DATA_FIM).values)
    
    print(dt_bitstamp.head()) #returning just the data in the defined time

    return dt_bitstamp
```

if needed, the csv dowload link is here >> https://www.kaggle.com/mczielinski/bitcoin-historical-data/data#coinbaseUSD_1-
min_data_2014-12-01_to_2019-01-09.csv

I'm new to pandas, so I'm lost.The objective is to calculate technical indicators with the data in the csv

Answer (score 0):

You can divide-to-rule the csv using chunks of some convenient size at csv reading and then concatenating them.

```
def getDataSetFile(file_path):
    dt_bitstamp = pd.read_csv(file_path, iterator=True, chunksize=10000)
    print(dt_bitstamp.head())

    dt_bitstamp = pd.concat(dt_bitstamp, ignore_index=True)

    dt_bitstamp = pd.DataFrame(dt_bitstamp, index=pd.date_range(DATA_INICIO, DATA_FIM).values)
    
    print(dt_bitstamp.head()) #returning just the data in the defined time

    return dt_bitstamp
```